# Permission denied running rake

Tags: centos, permission-denied

I'm getting a permission denied when running `rake bootstrap:all RAILS_ENV=production`.

I have given rwx permission to the *munkiserver* directory recursively. I have set umask to 022 in `/etc/profile`.

I don't know why `munkiserver_assets can't be created and what permissions it is requiring.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/munkiserver/../munkiserver_assets': Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you see that `/../` in the path? That means that the `munkiserver_assets` directory is created in *parent* (i.e. `/usr/share`) directory.

Comment: How can I temporarily make new installations in that folder use my username instead of root and have the correct file permissions required? Apart from creating the directory before hand.

Comment: If you want a system-wide installation, installed in a system directory, then you unfortunately need to do it as a system user (i.e. `root`). If you want a local installation only for you, in your own home-folder, then you should provide options to tell the `rake` program that.